# How to validate inputs on each step in a multi part form in vuejs?

Tags: forms, vue.js, vuejs2

I have created step in each tabs which represent the steps in the form. I have used v-if condition to check which step should be displayed. As of now the steps work perfectly fine when i click the next button. Even if the inputs are empty I am able to go to the next step. I want some validation on each step that will check if the input is empty and add a class to that input say "error-class". How do I do that in vuejs?
This is my form in .vue file.

```
<form id="product_form" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                    <!-- One "tab" for each step in the form: -->
                    <button type="button" v-if="step === 2 || step === 3 || step === 4" id="prevBtn1" @click.prevent="prev()"></button>

                    <div v-if="step === 1" class="tab">
                        <h3>Post a product</h3>
                        <div class="preview" id="preview">
                        </div>
                        <div class="single-holder">
                            <input type="text" name="pname" id="pname" placeholder="Title*" required="true" ref="pname">
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div v-if="step === 2" class="tab">
                        <h3>Describe your Product</h3>
                        <div class="descrip">
                            <textarea name="description" id="description" placeholder="Description" required="true"></textarea>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div v-if="step === 3" class="tab">
                        <h3>Set Inventory</h3>
                        <div class="fixed-width">
                            <div class="single-holder">
                                <label>Quantity</label>
                                <input type="number" name="quantity" id="quantity" required="true">
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div v-if="step === 4" class="tab">
                        <h3>Share On</h3>
                        <div class="address-details-holder clearfix">
                            <div class="single-holder">
                                <input placeholder="_ _ _ _" id="zipcode" name="zipcode" maxlength="4" type="text" @keypress="onlyNumber">
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </form>
```

This is my method in Vuejs

```
methods:{
onlyNumber ($event) {
   let keyCode = ($event.keyCode ? $event.keyCode : $event.which);
   if ((keyCode < 48 || keyCode > 57) && keyCode !== 46) { // 46 is dot
      $event.preventDefault();
   }
    },
prev() {
  this.step--;
},
next() {
    this.step++;
    //if(this.step===1){
        // console.log(this.$refs.name.value);
        //if(this.$refs.pname.value !== null){
        //  this.step++;
        //}
    //}
}
```

As of now the steps work fine if i remove the if condition in the function next() in methods. But I need input validations on each step so the user has to fill out the missing data in all the form fields.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you can use [Vee Validate](https://baianat.github.io/vee-validate/guide/) . It will help you check required in each input

```
<input v-validate="'required'" data-vv-as="field" name="required_field" type="text">
```

And return error message for that input if it false

```
<span>{{ errors.first('email') }}</span>
```

Comment: Will this work on each step or it triggers only on submit?

Comment: it triggers only on submit but you can set a variable in data to check on each step

Comment: managed to solve this by using this
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
if(this.step===1){
      if(this.$refs.pname.value !== ''){
       this.step++;
      }
     }